# how to route like file path in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a cloud file storage and I want to have `site.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt` URL and manage it.

what route should I add to manage this kind of URLs?

Comment: it url is real path to file? this part `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` is constant or number dirs may be change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for Asp.Net MVC Routing with Wildcards such as in http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/04/asp-net-mvc-routing-wildcard-parameters/

Comment: Better how? If you the file physically exists there is no need to use routing in any way. If the storage is managed by your application then you will need to deal with it using the route.